# Does one-to-one correspondence of the set of sample paths of $X$ and $Y$ imply that $X$ and $Y$ are indistinguishable?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, polya-urn-model

I have two discrete stochastic processes (urn models) $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$. There is a function $\varphi(.)$ such that whenever $\{x_0,x_1,...\}$ is a sample path of $X$ then $\{\varphi(x_0),\varphi(x_1),...\}$ is a sample path of $Y$. Similarly, whenever $\{y_0,y_1,...\}$ is a sample path of $Y$, $\{\varphi^{-1}(y_0),\varphi^{-1}(y_1),...\}$ is a sample path of $X$. There is, therefore, a one-to-one correspondence between the set of sample paths of $X$ and $Y$.
(1) Can we say that the set of sample paths are of equal size?
(2) There are two functions $f$ and $g$ that map $X$ and $Y$ into a discrete binary process $Z$ such that whenever $f$ maps a sample path $\mathbf{x}:\{x_0,x_1,...\}$ of $X$ into a sample path of binary variables $z=\{f(x_0),f(x_1),...\}$; $g$ maps $\{\varphi(x_0),\varphi(x_1),...\}$ to the same binary sample path $z$. i.e. $\mathbf{z}=\{f(x_0),f(x_1),...\}= \{g(\varphi(x_0)),g(\varphi(x_1)),...\}$. What can we say about $X$ and $Y$? Do we say that $X$ and $Y$ are projection-equivalent? Examples of $f: f(x)=1$ if $x>0.4, 0$ otherwise.
(3) The probability that each sample path $\mathbf{x}$ of $X$ and $\mathbf{y}=\varphi(\mathbf{x})$ of $Y$ occurs depends on the binary projected sample path $\mathbf{z}$. Do we have that $X$ and $Y$ have the same finite n-dimensional distributions? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $\phi$ is invertible correct? Also we are referring to continuous time discrete state space stochastic processes (some people refer to random sequences as being a sub-type of stochastic process, so I want to make sure I understand the question).

(1) If there is a bijection between the two sets of sample paths, then by the definition of cardinality they have the same cardinality.

(2) This seems to be more a property of the function $\phi$ than of X and Y.

(3) How would this necessarily be the case if f and g are not one-to-one? If the range of f and g has cardinality two (which you seem to be implying by describing z as being a binary stochastic process), then it seems unlikely that either f or g could be bijections.

Then there isn't a unique sample path of X and Y corresponding to any given binary sample path z (since the projection function isn't bijective), so although it might make sense to say that z depends on X or Y, it doesn't make sense to say that X or Y depends on z (since z doesn't determine any sample path X or Y uniquely).

**$\phi(x)$** and **y** have the same finite dimensional distributions, as do **x** and **$\phi^{-1}(y)$**.

The fact that $\phi$ is an invertible Borel function means that we can conceivably describe the distributions of **X** vis a vis **Y** and vice versa as push-forward/pull-backs of one another, but otherwise that doesn't make them equally distributed or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! It is a discrete time countable state space because the values $x$ and $y$ are proportions of balls in an urn. 
(1) $\varphi$ is indeed invertible. The two sets of sample paths have the same cardinality. 
(2) Consider the simple case where $y=(y_1,y_2)=a(x_1,x_2)$ and $f(x)=1$ if$ x\ge \frac{1}{2}, 0$ otherwise and $g(y)=1$ if $y \ge \frac{1}{2} a , 0$ otherwise i.e. $f(x)=1$ if and only if $g(y)=1$. Let $z=(z_1,z_2)=(f(x_1),f(x_2))=(g(y_1),g(y_2))$.<br/>

Comment: (3) Let $(x_{1,t+1},x_{2,t+1})=(\frac{t\times x_{1,t}+f(x_{2,t})}{t+1},\frac{t\times x_{2,t}+f(x_{1,t})}{t+1})$; therefore the transition from $(x_{1,t},x_{2,t})$ to $(x_{1,t+1},x_{2,t+1})$ depends on $(f(x_{1,t},f(x_{2,t}))$ i.e. on $(z_1,z_2)$.

Comment: So are we assuming that this is a Markov chain? I thought you were referring to the general law of X and Y (i.e. given an initial condition), not just the conditional law (i.e. the transition probabilities).

Comment: Yepp! I should have mentioned that! It is a Markov chain! The trick is that we are interested in the convergence of $Z(t)$. I am looking for a way to phrase properly the fact that the two variables $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ project to the same binary variable $Z(t)$. If it is the case, can we say that they are equivalent in some way? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? I am not certain what you are getting at. From what you wrote, it seems like $f\circ \phi = g$, where $\phi$ is invertible. This is just a consequence of the fact that $\phi(X) ~ Y$, $\phi$ invertible. Such a relationship is useful for calculating the distribution (in particular the distribution) of one RV in terms of that of the other, for example, or calculating Gaussian distributed numbers using a uniform number generator.

Comment: To be more clear: the projection equivalence you mention is an artifact (at least in my opinion) of the equivalence of the two distributions up to an invertible function. This is an equivalence relation (i.e. f ~ g iff f = $\phi \circ g$, $\phi$ invertible). In general, in probability and other fields, this is called "change of variables". I guess you could say something like X(t) and Y(t) "can be described as the same process in different coordinate systems". At least in differential topology/geometry and mathematical physics, I know that changes of variables play an even more fundamental

Comment: role than in probability theory; for instance in the definition of a manifold, as well as in the frequent use of pullbacks and push-forwards (inverse, implicit function theorems). The more properties that $\textit{both}$ $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ have, the "stronger" the equivalence between the two functions (coordinate systems); e.g. homeomorphisms, diffeomorphisms, etc. Now that you mention it, there probably should be a name in general for "equivalence up to an invertible function"; it is a frequently encountered concept. There probably is, I just don't know it. Anyway, idk how to help more.